# xlwings persistent Python objects

Tags: python, excel, macos, xlwings

I would like to be able to have persistent Python objects accessible from Excel using `xlwings`. I am using `RunPython` because I am on a Mac. Does anyone have any ideas how I can create persistent objects? For example:

```
Sub MySub()
    RunPython ("from mod import MyClass;c = MyClass()")
End Sub

Sub MySubSequent()
    RunPython ("c.call_function()")
End Sub
```

Calling `MySub` would create a `MyClass` instance, and subsequently `MySubSequent` would access it.

I thought about running a Python script that opens a workbook, but `RunPython` calls would create a new process, so that gains me nothing.

I *think* maybe this could be done using UDFs, but since I can't test it, I am not sure (it would still be nice to know if that is an option).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also replied to a similar issue on GitHub and got an answer. I won't paste it here in case it gets updated in the future: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/621#issuecomment-642461322